# Form Fields Not Fitting Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement a bootstrap modal form in my Django project.  When I do this, everything works except the fields are running much wider than the modal window and seem strangely offset.  I feel like there's an easy fix here but I can't determine exactly what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my html for the modal form:

modal.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

 <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Create new Book</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    {{form.Reference_Number|as_crispy_field}}
    {{form.Ultimate_Consignee|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Create</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing each crispy form field inside a Bootstrap `form-group` `<div>` container. Like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    {{form.Reference_Number|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{form.Ultimate_Consignee|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[More on info on Bootstrap forms here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply - no no luck with this either.  I'm pretty confused because I've done this in a previous project which I'm comparing against and I have it exactly as it is there. Also noticed that even if I try to not use crispy fields this still happens. Any other thought?

Comment: Try inspecting the rendered form fields with the Browser's developers tools. This should show us how the input fields are getting rendered and where.

Comment: Thank you! That was a helpful reminder - I had some styling done on the form-control bootstrap class applying margin for a different element not realizing the same class was assigned to inputs when using crispy forms. Thanks for the assistance. @JuanMarco

Comment: Happy to help @GXM100.